# Windows can't identify Samsung captivate glide

Tags: samsung-kies, usb-drivers, samsung-captivate-glide

I've *Samsung Captivate Glide* (i927). When I try to connect the phone to the PC windows says `USB Device unrecognized`. I've installed the latest version of *Samsung Kies*, and also installed `Samsung_USB_Driver_for_Mobile_Phones_v1.5.14.0` from the official Samsung site. Still I cannot connect my phone to the PC.

I tried to install the Samsung mobile composite driver manually also. It installed successfully but gives an error that the device cannot start code 10. And again the phone is detected as "Unknown device".

I've also tried to change the PDA USB mode in phoneutils by `*#7284#`, still no luck.

Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem? I'm using Windows-7 Ultimate 32-bit Desktop computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got solution after 2 days of headache. Problem is my USB data cable. I've got original Samsung's USB data cable with phone but unfortunately it is not working. Though charging can done via this cable. I've tries few Chinese cables also but problem remains there. But as soon as I use my friend's original Samsung cable it working like a charm.

So any of you have this problem first thing to do is check from another usb cable. And importantly go for OEM's original cable.